# Modifying dropdown_sections.pt (webcouturier.dropdownmenu)

Tags: plone

Does anyone have any experience modifying the dropdown_sections.pt through the ZMI? It's the page template that comes with webcouturier.dropdownmenu. I would like to modify it and make it into a mega menu (one that supports columns)? Is it possible?

I am using plone.app.theming to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

That template is not exposed in portal_view_customizations.  It is being called from the file system.

If you want mega menu, try [collective.collage.megamenu](https://plone.org/products/collective.collage.megamenu)

Comment: Trying to turn webcouturier.dropdownmenu into a megamenu might be possible, using the techniques below, but unless you are already really good at this stuff, it's probably better to trying using the product h2o suggests in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.themingplugins addon in your Plone site. You just have to add a folder in your theme:

```
overrides
```

and add a file named

```
webcouturier.dropdownmenu.browser.dropdown_sections.pt
```

with the content of the official one (you can copy paste it from githuba https://github.com/collective/webcouturier.dropdownmenu/blob/master/src/webcouturier/dropdownmenu/browser/dropdown_sections.pt

```
<tal:sections tal:define="portal_tabs view/portal_tabs"
 tal:condition="portal_tabs"
 i18n:domain="plone">
<h5 class="hiddenStructure" i18n:translate="heading_sections">Sections</h5>

<ul id="portal-globalnav"
    tal:define="selected_tab python:view.selected_portal_tab"
    ><tal:tabs tal:repeat="tab portal_tabs"
    ><li tal:define="tid tab/id;
                     subitems python:view.getTabObject(tabUrl = tab['url'], tabPath = tab.get('path'));
                     item_clickable python:view.enable_parent_clickable or not subitems"
         tal:attributes="id string:portaltab-${tid};
                         class python:selected_tab==tid and 'selected' or 'plain'"
        ><a href=""
           tal:content="tab/name"
           tal:attributes="href tab/url;
                           title tab/description|nothing;
                           class python:item_clickable and 'plain' or 'noClick'">
        Tab Name
        </a
        ><tal:block tal:condition="subitems">
            <ul class="submenu">
                <tal:subitems tal:replace="structure subitems">
                    <tal:comment replace="nothing">Submenu</tal:comment>
                </tal:subitems>
            </ul>
        </tal:block></li></tal:tabs></ul>
</tal:sections>
```

On how you have to do a megamenu, its up to you. The plone stuff is here resolved.